# APF firewall & IPset

Tags: iptables, ipset

Due to too many hack attempts from spam countries, today got the server configured with IPset for iptables.

I loaded thousands of ip range in IPset & then added it to iptables with this command

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --set Cblock src -j DROP
```

Cblock is the name I gave for the ipset rule containing 20 countries ip range

All is good! but the moment I start APF firewall, ipset rules no longer in effect even though it still shows up in the status.

```
service iptables status
```

I checked APF config file & there is no mention about IPset. I also tried to start APF first & then load IPset rules. This approach also did not make a difference.

Anyone had similar circumstance to tackle? I use APF to deal with spamhouse ip's, port blocking etc.

Is there any other firewall wrapper that is compatible with IPset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not related to ipset at all.

If you have any manual configuration in iptables, APF simply replaces them with their own rules.

Use `iptables -L` to check if your rule is still present and reachable.

Starting APF first and adding your rule afterwards should work. Be aware that `iptable -A` adds a rule at the end after all the other rules. If APF accepts the connection, your rule will never be reached. Use `iptables -I` to insert a rule at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Type `ipset --list` and see what is in the list.